# Different values for integer

Tags: c++, c++11

Trying to insert values of square and cube of a number in set st and st1. (Let n = 10^7).
After printing, set st is having negative values due to limit of integer but there are no negative values in set st1 even though both 'i' and 'temp' are integers.

```
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        int temp = 2;
        set<int> st;
        set<int> st1;

        while ((temp * temp) < n)
        {
            st.insert(temp * temp);
            if ((temp * temp * temp) < n)
            {
                st.insert(temp * temp * temp);
            }
            temp++;
        }

        for(int i=1;i*i<n;i++){
            st1.insert(i * i);
        }
        for(int i=1;i*i*i<n;i++){
            st1.insert(i* i * i);
        }

        for(auto ss : st){
            cout<<ss<<" ";
        }

        cout<<"\n\n";

        for(auto s : st1){
            cout<<s<<" ";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Overflowing signed integer types in arithmetic operations results in undefined behavior. There is no wrap-around to negative values.

Comment: @user17732522 but its working with for loop but not with while loop.

Comment: For the reason above your program has undefined behavior with input `10000000`, see https://godbolt.org/z/zvYvG1sGe.

Comment: Undefined behavior means that there is no guarantee whether or not the program will behave in the way you expect it to.

Comment: Your `while` loop reaches higher values of `temp ^ 3` than `i ^ 3` in your `for` loop.

Comment: @user17732522 then why is it working with for loop? It should have Undefined behavior then also.

Comment: "_no guarantee whether or not the program will behave in the way you expect it to_".

Comment: Sorry, if you remove the `while` loop there is no integer overflow at all for the reason mentioned in the comment by @tromgy, see https://godbolt.org/z/G1jKj8enG. Nonetheless, the `while` loop has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of `temp * temp < n` is undefined if `temp * temp` overflows the type. Wraparound to negative is commonly observed but even with architectures that do that, optimising compilers are permitted to assume that if `a + c < b + c` for a constant `c` then `a < b`.

`temp < n / temp` is a common refactoring that does not suffer from that overflow. You do of course need to check for non-zero `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop stops once the first cube reaches 10^7.
But your while loop continues until the first sqare reaches 10^7. At this point (n=3163) the cube already exceeded INT_MAX.